# 400 Bad Request - https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Tags: google-oauth

can anyone please tell me why this is bad request

```
var searchurl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url:searchurl,
        context: {code:auth_code, client_id:'clientid', client_secret:'secret', redirect_uri:'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8085%2FGmailIntegration%2FgetAuthResponse.jsp', grant_type:'authorization_code'},
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            console.log(jqXHR);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The correct way to draw attention to an unanswered question is to edit the question and improve it (clarify it, format it, see if you can clearly state the question without having any extra length). Do not post a duplicate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [400 Bad Request when sending http post request to get token from auth code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219994/400-bad-request-when-sending-http-post-request-to-get-token-from-auth-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working.. i am sharing the code for those who are stuck with this:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url:searchurl,
        data: {code:code, client_id:'clientid', client_secret:'secret', redirect_uri:'http://localhost:8085/GmailIntegration/getAuthResponse.jsp', grant_type:'authorization_code'},
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain:true,
        cache : true, 
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception, errorstr) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            alert(errorstr);
        }
    });
```

but now i have new issue. The url get 200 OK response but i am not getting response at all

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 user agent flow is recommended for JS clients, see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Is there any specific reason you want to use the web server flow in a JS app?