# getting access tokens forbidden 403 and some times 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, httpwebrequest

I am facing the following issue while issuing request to retrieve the access token. First, I registered the application in developer console and consequently downloaded the client secret file. The content of which is as below: (i have marked secrets as xxxxx).

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"xxxx","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"xxxx","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

In the developer documentation (located at : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp ) however, it is given a different address to connect and retrieve the access tokens.

POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I am confused 
1. which URI's to use to get access to tokens. 
2. What redirect_uri should be used? Is it the local host or the uri  as noted in the developer documentation.

When i use the client secret token uri, i receive a 400 bad request and when i use the uri as noted in the developer documentation, I receive forbidden 403.

```
POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Can someone kindly clarify. It would be an immense help. 
I am writing a console application and i do not want to use the C# api already provided. The sample code is located below.

Where am I doing wrong?

```
        string tokenUri = @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        HttpWebRequest request=(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(tokenUri);


        NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("code", this.clientCode);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("client_id", this.clientID);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("client_secret", this.clientSecret);
        outgoingQueryString.Add("redirect_uri", "https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code");
        outgoingQueryString.Add("grant_type","authorization_code");
        string postdata = outgoingQueryString.ToString();


        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream reqStr = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStr.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        reqStr.Flush();
        reqStr.Close();


        HttpWebResponse response=request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
```

Found out that url-encoded is not to be used, instead json is expected. revised the code as below and still 400 persist.

```
string tokenUri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        TokenFileds f = new TokenFileds() { client_code = this.clientCode, client_id = this.clientID, client_secret = this.clientSecret, redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", grant_type = "authorization_code" };
        //string retString=this.SerializeToJson<TokenFileds>(f);
        string retString = this.NewjsonLib(f);
        byte[] byteArray=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(retString);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tokenUri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream strm = request.GetRequestStream();
        strm.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        strm.Flush();
        strm.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response =request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: This might help http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/   but any reason you are doing it like this and not using Googles client library? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/

Comment: I wanted to develop my own lib. The reason being, I didn't liked the way they wrote the interfaces to code.In the link that you have posted, is the code ... part of the url or the post body. i assume from the documentation that it is url encoded body.

Comment: check the json data you posted.  that is not the redirect uri that you are sending in your code they must be the same.

Comment: I have changed the redirect uri to "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" as per the link. Also, i found that the data is not be url encoded, it must be json. So, repacked the code with newtonsoft.json which yields the following output. "{\"client_code\":\"4/sZ7URBc5qJ6vYt5t3dLz_xyZH-r-ptZdxCZTkx9hdYo\",\"client_id\":\"755933294823-t0afvat7k75c49io03o8c0noer7m17m9.apps.googleusercontent.com\",\"client_secret\":\"9e1JLC1Tawra4xZwCTHxxT2h\",\"redirect_uri\":\"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob\",\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\"}".  But still the same problem. @DaImTo. 400 Bad Request. Am i missing something ?

Comment: you are not using the json file are you you are doing this the hard way. Read the first link I sent you it will walk you though what each request needs to look like http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/  If you did around my site long enough you will probably find a post about how to do this I C# I have a really old post about this somewhere.

Comment: http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/ yup that's old

Comment: @DamTo: This is the revised code:

Comment: What do you mean by revised code?  I think you should read the links I posted you they have working examples of how to do this.  If you are Posting it Json that probably explains why its not working.

Comment: checking this post yields that it is json that is expected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219994/400-bad-request-when-sending-http-post-request-to-get-token-from-auth-code

Comment: So you don't want to check the pages I linked you with articles on exactly how to get this working with C#?  You would rather look at pages about JavaScript and Ajax options?  I am sorry I am not very good at JavaScript or Ajax I don't think I can help you anymore.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you need to insure few things before as,
1. While creating the project you have to select other type project.
2. You must enable the drive API's.
3. Then make sure you are posting this url L"/o/oauth2/token"  to this server L"accounts.google.com".
4. you are giving Content Type as L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

5.and your header should be like this,
 wstring wstrHeader = L"code="+ m_wstrAuthCode +
L"&client_id=327293200239-4n4a8ej3jlm1fdufqu7httclg5a28m1a.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=ieEGhWhPhotp0ZegdgRLkOxv&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code";

here you have to replace m_wstrAuthCode to your authentication code.

6.then you will get the Json from server as,

{
  "access_token" :  "ya29.7gGjEgvIVIMOO7bHegijk2KygAVjjxz7bCOxUvG7OKeKTc66Nom1e9zCqSyzR4V0bTYC",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/Vc9A7nfib4ikeYs0-TBfrs-isvjRDt-JI2ftj0pNVcRIgOrJDtdun6zK6XiATCKT"
}
7.you need to parse it to get the access token.