# ERROR: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: vb.net

I am using aspx vb .net to connect with instagram api

I am using the following link as references: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Haroon-Said-e1d8d388

> ERROR: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

It is weird becuase i followed all steps and imported json as showed in above link. any idea? below is my code:

```
Dim json As String = ""
Try
  Dim parameters As New NameValueCollection
  parameters.Add("client_id", Client_ID)
  parameters.Add("client_secret", ClientSecret)
  parameters.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
  parameters.Add("redirect_uri", Redirect_URI)
  parameters.Add("code", Code)
  Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
  Try
    'ERROR HERE
    Dim result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "POST", parameters)
    ...
  Catch ex As Exception
    labelTest.Text += "---" & ex.Message
  End Try
```

---

Thanks. yeah I been working on this for couple months now and trying to debug but I just have no idea whats going on. I mean I looked at insta api webbsite sill no luck. I tested my values also and they seem to be correct:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token



client_secret = f208d9fc9cec4b69bdd5f8f1386a 
 client_secret = d836619eede4490fd12983b95961 
 grant_type = authorization_code 
 redirect_uri = http://localhost:1861/UI/Home.aspx 
 code = 6185508825da0c28a33ac5dcc77
```

note, 'code' i am getting when when user logs into insta. I used the following url to get the code: 
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

I know authorize is correct becuase it gives me code in url

Comment: You probably want to change that client_secret before bad people use it.

Comment: Your link is missing information because it's broken

Comment: thanks, I have updated the link and no worryies i have change the id.

Comment: I suggest you modify your Try/Catch to include a catch for types of WebException.  WebExceptions can include a Response stream property which may contain more error information from the server.  This is a good change overall, even if it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: You probably have to send it a JSON. you can look here too. OAuth2 is a standard. Google,Instagram, etc they all use OAuth2. it's widely use and accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219994/400-bad-request-when-sending-http-post-request-to-get-token-from-auth-code

Comment: thanks! i think ajax json parts comes after you get access_token... issue that i am having is that I can't get pass this part: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

Comment: any idea how can I get more detail info in try/catch block?

Answer (score 0):

solved!

just changed response_type from code to token... it will give you access_token